# Where can I view new lore entries?

Tags: diablo-iii

My level 2 barbarian was killing zombies right outside of town when a little box in the bottom right appeared which said "New Lore". Since I was in the middle of combat I didn't have time to click on it, and a moment later it faded out and disappeared.

I assume there is somewhere that I can view this lore, but the most likely candidate, my Journal, only seems to have quest information and a book from Leah that I found in town. Where can I view lore information?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press the `L` key.  This will show your journal.  By default, entries are ordered by most recent.

Sometime, a previous journal entry is shown and you will need to click 'Back' to see the full list.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what had happened. I looked there, but I'd previously had Leah's entry open, so I needed to hit the "Back" button from there to get to the full list.