# Can I read or listen to a creature lore if I missed the popup?

Tags: diablo-iii

When I am questing and/or exploring in diablo 3, I sometimes miss the *New Lore* popup in the bottom right corner of my screen.  After a short period of time, it disappears.  Can I read or listen to this lore or is it lost till my next play through ?

Comment: I have found the lore or lores collection under the quest menu but the lores dont seem new to me. ( that I have discovered a new one)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I view new lore entries?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49347/where-can-i-view-new-lore-entries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Press "J" to open your quest journal.  Click on the Journal tab, and you can review all the lore you've collected including listening to it.

It shows the "Most Recent" by default, but you can choose whether you want it to show Quest, World, People or Bestiary lore.

Comment: Do you have listen to a lore to unlock the lores achievements ? Or do you just have to pick them up?

Comment: Just pick them up.  I've interrupted mine a couple of times and still got credit.