# Is it possible to visualize in-game the transcription of lore books?

Tags: diablo-iii

Scattered around the world, there are the various books that provide a little XP bonus and some lore informations through a spoken-only text.

Is it possible to activate a close captioning or at least an in-game transcription of those books?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I view new lore entries?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49347/where-can-i-view-new-lore-entries)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open up your Journal (by default, the key to do so is L) - there should be a tab with a list of all the lore items you've found. Clicking one will expand it to show a transcription of its text and the option to listen to it again.